# Spring Config file to have different bean data populated based on input

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I am new to Java spring framwork. I am using the spring framework do the the functional test. As a part of testing, I have file that need to pass to API and validate from the DB, that the file data is goes into DB.  I have using spring to store the test file with associated data data. . My test has to call API with multiple files . How can from the spring file properties

DifferentValuesInBeanForFile1 ( see spring file ) = Some bean that has data associated with file 1. 
DifferentValuesInBeanForFile2 = Some bean that has data associated with file 2.

So test can validate API correctly processed input file 1 by validatitng data

```
<bean id="TestHappyPathPostDeal1Hotel1Deal" class="com.abc.FunctionalTests">
    <property name="InDate" value="12/20/2014 00:00:00" />
    <property name="OutDate" value="12/24/2014 00:00:00" />
    <property name="HotelDeals">
        <util:map>
            <entry InputFile="fileWithDeal123.avro" value="DifferentValuesInBeanForFile1" />
            <entry InputFile="fileWithDeal999.avro" value="DifferentValuesInBeanForFile1" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question properly. However if I do, then you need to look at using properties. You can add this at the top of your spring file:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
            <list>
                    <value>file:///opt/somelocation/general.properties</value>
            </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you can reference stuff from in there inside your spring file:

```
<bean id="config" class="com.something.SomeClassConfiguration">
    <property name="hosts" value="${main.hosts}" />
    <property name="clusterName" value="${main.clusterName}" />
</bean>
```

Where your general.properties file contains something like:

```
main.hosts=127.0.0.1:9160
main.clusterName=test
```

If you then what to change that depending on your compile, you need to look at your build system. I use maven, and have profiles setup. Depending on what I'm doing I get maven to replace general.properties file with the correct file for the system I'm building.

Hope that helps.